# Using the definite article "the" with Company Name + Group denominations

Tags: definite-articles

Is it correct to use the definite article "the" with Company Name + Group denominations, like "the ExxonMobil Group", "the Total Group", "the General Motors Group"? Or is it better without, like "ExxonMobil Group", "Total Group", "General Motors Group"?

Comment: Probably yes, but some context would help. Could you give an example in a sentence?

Comment: Thanks."The current corporate structure of the ExxonMobil
group is the result of a series of multi-stage corporate developments

Comment: your example sentence perfectly reflects the answer I wrote below, so you're on the right track!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the same formulation as the company itself uses. Have a quick look at the "About Us" tab on their websites - for example, [ExxonMobil](http://corporate.exxonmobil.com/en/company/about-us) refers to itself as ExxonMobil - no "the" or "Group" - and it's the same with [General Motors](http://www.gm.com/company/about-gm.html).

If "Group" is not an official part of the company's name but you want to reflect that the company has various incorporated entities related to it, then it would be appropriate to add "the" before the company name and "group" (**not** capitalised) after: hence "the ExxonMobil group".

Comment: Thanks! Very exhaustive and useful! I agree "group" should not be capitalized in case it is not part of the denomination of the company.